# how to extend attributes using XML Schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have on the XML:

```
<Devices>
    <Device name="Phone" number="123456789"/>
    <Device name="Computer" ip="192.168.0.1"/>
</Devices>
```

and I want to set an Schema for this, where I have 'devices' and I can declare a device, but if the device has the name="phone" a number has to be declared as required, but if the device is name="computer", well, the ip is required just for 'computer'

is there a way to do this, is it possible?

Comment: You could name your elements `<Phone/>` and `<Computer/>` *directly* and then have control over their content models separately, or you could use Conditional Type Assignment in XSD 1.1.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are taking the right approach with this (unless you have no choice in the design of the XML). It would be better I think, to define separate elements for Phone and Computer. I don't even know if its possible to change the types of attributes based on the value of an attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be the XML schema

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0"
    targetNamespace="stackoverflow" xmlns:tns="stackoverflow"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="Devices" type="tns:deviceListType" />

    <xs:complexType name="deviceListType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Device" type="tns:deviceType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="deviceType">

    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="computerType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="tns:deviceType">
                <xs:attribute name="name">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value="Computer" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:attribute>
                <xs:attribute name="ip" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="phoneType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="tns:deviceType">
                <xs:attribute name="name">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value="Phone" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:attribute>
                <xs:attribute name="number" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

And this would be a sample XML document

```
<sf:Devices xmlns:sf="stackoverflow"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="stackoverflow test.xsd">
    <sf:Device xsi:type="sf:computerType" name="Computer" ip="1"/>
    <sf:Device xsi:type="sf:phoneType" name="Phone" number="2"/>
</sf:Devices>
```

Sorry if the original XSD sample was confusing.

Comment: sorry I am kind of new here, could you please explain more this answer? :D thanks

Comment: The idea behind the sample above (untested) was to use XML extensibility to create 2 subclasses of the device type.

I updated the answer with the XSD I tested this afternoon.